# How do I watch 1080p video on this setup computer without lagg?

Tags: windows-7, media-player, codec, amd-radeon, blu-ray

My hardware:

```
CPU:     Q6600 @ 2.4GHz
RAM:     4GB
GPU:     Radeon HD5750
OS:      Windows 7 Ultimate x64
Codecs:  K-lite codec pack default install
```

I'm trying to watch a 1080p bluray movie backup by opening the m2ts files in Media player classic. By my computer specs you'd think I could handle 1080p video, but when watching in media player classic it runs "smoothly" for about 3 seconds, then skips forward a few seconds, and runs smoothly, then skips. It's as if my PC is unable to play at the full 30 fps framerate, so plays at 25fps until the frame queue just dumps several seconds-worth of frames onto the screen in an instance (and repeat).

Can a software adjustment help me here? Alternative player (with frameskip option), alternative codecs-

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, very perplexing situation; with those specs one would definitely expect better performance. Have you tried playing those same media files on another computer? It's possible that the files themselves are corrupted, which could be causing the skipping.

I would also suggest trying some other players to see if they work any better. [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.m2ts#Software_support), some M2TS files can be played by a variety of media player programs, listed in said article. The ones I would recommend trying are Windows Media Player, which has very good codec support in Windows 7, and VLC, which can play just about anything.

Comment: Amazingly enough, Windows Media Player plays the video perfectly, way better than VLC or Media Player Classic (which both skipped and lagged). I'd have never thought of using WMP to play 1080p video. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Glad that worked for you! Yep, WMP in Windows 7 is actually pretty nice; I use it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

- I suggest you use **VLC** or **CyberLink PowerDVD** not K-Lite Codec. when some processes take more CPU usage the K-Lite codec lags if it is playing HD videos.
- For more information VLc (free), go here http://www.videolan.org/vlc/
- For more information Cyberlink Power DVD (not free), go here http://www.cyberlink.com/
- Another possibility is that some Computer are unable to display HD videos if you have a CRT monitor

Answer (score 1):

If your M2TS files contain H.264 video, try the CoreAVC decoder. It's extremely fast and works great with Media Player Classic.

- http://www.free-codecs.com/download/Codec.htm

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [kmplayer](http://kmplayer.en.softonic.com/) or [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/).  KMplayer comes with codecs already installed, and typically doesn't need anymore codecs installed.  XBMC may need the H.264 codec installed, but that's pretty easy to fine.  My guess is that your software isn't the best for the video format.  I have a core two duo laptop with 4 gig ram and windows 7 x64 and 1080p works fine with both of these video players even when streaming across my wireless network.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried lot of things with .m2ts format. And I have smooth playback with those software:

- [ffdshow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow/)
- [Haali Media Splitter](http://haali.su/mkv/)
- [KMPlayer](http://kmplayer.en.softonic.com/)

In kmplayer options you have possibility to scan system for codecs/splitters/etc and assign Haali splitter to mpeg2-ts playback.

Note: K-lite codec pack, VLC player, MPC-HC doesn't even let me to play .mt2s at all (just notify that codec has not been found)

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure all your drivers are updated (mainboard and video card especially) and clean up any unnecessary applications that may be starting with Windows. Also, set your pagefile (system cache) to a set size that does not allow dynamic expansion and shrinkage. All these steps will free up resources for the system.

I've been able to play full screen 1080p video on a Windows 7 laptop without video card drivers (the system was 7 years old and the intel integrated "crap"hics didn't support the Win7 driver model at all), 2GB memory, and a Core2 processor running 1.8Ghz. Cleaning the system up and minimizing extraneous resource usage was the key to that.

Also, I've found a lot of success using the CCCP (Combined Community Codec Pack) and Media Player Classic tends to be the best at handling most video types on a low resource system or on a system where resource usage is a concern.